# lock statement not working when there is a loop inside it?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

See this code:

```
public class multiply
{
    public Thread myThread;
    public int Counter
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public string name
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public void RunConsolePrint()
    {

        lock(this)
        {
        RunLockCode("lock");
        }


    }

    private void RunLockCode(string lockCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Now thread "+lockCode+" " + name + " has started");
        for (int i = 1; i <= Counter; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(lockCode+" "+name + ": count has reached " + i + ": total count is " + Counter);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Thread " + lockCode + " " + name + " has finished");
    }
    public multiply(string pname, int pCounter)
    {
        name = pname;
        Counter = pCounter;
        myThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(RunConsolePrint));
    }

}
```

And this is the test run code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int counter = 50;

        multiply m2 = new multiply("Second", counter);
        multiply m1 = new multiply("First", counter);
        m1.myThread.Start();
        m2.myThread.Start();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

I would expect that `m2` must execute from start to finish before `m1` starts executing, or vice versa, because of the `lock` statement. But the result I found was the call to lock first and lock second was intermingled together, i.e., something like this

```
Now thread lock First has started
Now thread lock Second has started
lock First: Count has reached 1: total count is 50
lock First: Count has reached 2: total count is 50
lock Second: Count has reached 1: total count is 50
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Each instance of the code is locking on a different object.  Your lock object needs to be shared between all instances -- make it a static class variable.

```
private static object syncRoot = new object();
public void RunConsolePrint()
{
    lock(syncRoot)
    {
         RunLockCode("lock");
    }    
}
```

Comment: From a design point of view, I don't really like the idea of locking a static variable. I prefer to see shared state passed into each object's constructor, preferably in a way which prevents external classes from accessing the shared state.